# Decentralization in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have datatable Location(LocaID, LocaName, Parent). Now, I want bind to dropdownlist like this structure:

```
Parent 1

----Child 1.1

----Child 1.2

Parent 2

----Child 2.1

----Child 2.2

Parent 3
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use this : http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/how-to/grouping-items

Comment: and the parents can not be selcted?

Comment: @शेखर Parents can be selected

Comment: @SankarRaj It's not work for my situation, in my dropdownlist, parent can be selected

Comment: I think you should look for some jquery add on for this. See this link hope it help you. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-Checboxes-multiselect/